# Mongo Java - prefexing a field value with some constant in all the docs

Tags: java, mongodb

I have so many documents in a collection and would like to change one of the filed name in all the documents. Also, want to change the value with some prefixed constant in all the docs.

Example,

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56e9e6e9083378ba4e5e8832"), 
  "name" : "Mike" 
}

Should be changed to,

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56e9e6e9083378ba4e5e8832"), 
  "firstName" : "First-Mike" 
}
```

I used the following Java code to rename the field,

```
final MongoDatabase mongoDb = mongo.getDatabase(database);

            final MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDb.getCollection("<CollectionName>");

            Bson rename = Updates.rename("name", "firstName"); 

            collection.updateMany(new Document(), rename);
```

But not sure, how to change the value with some prefixed constants for all the documents in the collection.

I can iterate all the documents in the collection and do the change, but trying to understand, if there is any way we can do this without iterating all the documents, like single update.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regular expressions for prefix matching? A single update command can do your job if you use mongodb's regex:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/